# Как вывести данный и данного js кода

Tags: javascript

Я подключаю данную js на своём домене.
Как мне вывести из неё "data"? alert(__func)?

```
if(typeof __func==='function')__func({"data":{"user":"123"},"status":"Cool"});
```

Код подключается так:

```
<script src=example.com/user-data.js></script>
```

Comment: что значит _подключаю данную js на своём домене_? Что мешает взять нужные данные сразу, раз они известны и так?

Comment: Данные изначально не известны. Они генерируются на стороннем сайте на основе cookie пользователя.

Comment: Я ничего не понял.  "подключаю данную js" - почему "данная js" женского рода?

Comment: как именно ты подключаешь этот код?

Comment: <script src=example.com/user-data.js></script>

Comment: @asfasfasdgasg, внутри `example.com/user-data.js` только указанная строка кода расположена?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае похоже на реализацию `jsonp`, просто имя callback-функции жестко забито в ответе, а не указывается в адресе.

Для получения данных, достаточно объявить указанную функцию до подключения файла

```
<script>
    function __func(obj) {
        console.log('data:', obj.data); 
    }
</script>
<script src=example.com/user-data.js></script>
```

В этом случае, после загрузки скрипта он проверит, что такая функция есть и вызовет ее передав объект с данными в качестве параметра.